# OpsHub Migration from TFS 2010 Scrum Version 1 to Visual Studio Online Scrum 2013.3

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

Migration fails with error message 'Template customization or template mismatch error'.
But we used a really not customized process template: Scrum Version 1.

For evaluation purposes we created a new team project on TFS 2010 by use of the Scrum Version 1 process template. We entered some work items and source code.

On Visual Studio Online side we created a project of same name by use of the process template Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 2013.3.

Migration failed with the error message you find above.

We need this scenario because our real team project located on TFS 2010 is based on Scrum Version 1 process template.

Are there any ideas on how to succeed?

Thank in advance for proposals and solutions.

Regards,
Andi

Comment: Hi Andi, To find mismatch between templates you can use [TFS Team Project Manager on CodePlex](https://teamprojectmanager.codeplex.com), this will compare your team project's process template with baseline scrum process template to help you find the differences. You can create a default scrum team project on new TFS server and compare against current team project using scrum version 1

Comment: I learned that current version OVSMU-V1.1.0.005 does not support Visual Studio Scrum 1.0 Process Template because it wasn’t available out of the box in TFS 2010 - but that you scheduled to make it supported early February 2015. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

To find mismatch between templates you can use [TFS Team Project Manager on CodePlex](https://teamprojectmanager.codeplex.com), this will compare your team project's process template with baseline scrum process template to help you find the differences. You can create scrum team project on new TFS server and compare against current team project using scrum version 1

Comment: Hi all.
We used a baseline scrum version 1 process template.
Can you confirm that the migration of work items of a TFS 2010 team project based on unchanged Scrum Version 1 template to VSO team project based on Scrum 2013.3 template works?
Regards,
Andi